# Meteor Subscription hook?

Tags: meteor

I have a really stupid question on the subscription hook function on the routecontroller.

I don't really know where the .ready variable or method come from, is it with the built in variable for the subscription?

```
PostsListController = RouteController.extend({
  template: 'postsList',
  increment: 5, 
  postsLimit: function() { 
    return parseInt(this.params.postsLimit) || this.increment; 
  },
  findOptions: function() {
    return {sort: {submitted: -1}, limit: this.postsLimit()};
  },
  subscriptions: function() {
    this.postsSub = Meteor.subscribe('posts', this.findOptions());
  },
  posts: function() {
    return Posts.find({}, this.findOptions());
  },
  data: function() {
    var hasMore = this.posts().count() === this.postsLimit();
    var nextPath = this.route.path({postsLimit: this.postsLimit() + this.increment});
    return {
      posts: this.posts(),
      ready: this.postsSub.ready,
      nextPath: hasMore ? nextPath : null
    };
  }
});
```

Comment: Your `this.ready()` variable is derived from anything the router puts into the wait queue `this.wait( ... )`. Subscriptions add the subscription into the wait queue but does not automatically use the loading template like the `waitOn:` hook does. - https://github.com/iron-meteor/iron-router/blob/devel/Guide.md#wait-and-ready

Comment: `ready` is actually a method of the subscription handle (the object returned by `Meteor.subscribe`).

Comment: i thought this.postsSub.ready is variable?